# Display Time values on line chart Y axis with React Chart.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datetime, chart.js

I am trying to display the values from this object on a React Chart.js line chart:
The times are formatted as hours, minutes, and seconds.

```
  {
    "totaltime": "10:55:41",
    "date": "2018-01-01T00:00:00"
  },
  {
    "totaltime": "339:40:53",
    "date": "2019-01-01T00:00:00"
  },
  {
    "totaltime": "227:25:42",
    "date": "2020-01-01T00:00:00"
  },
  {
    "totaltime": "286:40:01",
    "date": "2021-01-01T00:00:00"
  },
]
```

I then use this function to add the time values to the line chart component:

```
function getChartData(documents, label, color) {

  return {
    labels: documents.map((document) => document.date),
    datasets: [
      {
        label: label,
        data: documents.map((document) => document.totaltime),
        backgroundColor: color,
        borderColor: color,
        borderWidth: 1,
      },
    ],
  };
}
```

However only the dates display and no data appears on the X-axis. If I change the values from date objects to seconds, they display perfectly but I want users to see the data in hours and minutes instead of seconds.

I have tried sending the data as seconds and then formatting the output to hours and minutes with the date-fns library using the Chart.js options, but the values never changed and stayed as seconds.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution to get the time values without replacing your date labels after using Remesh's answer**

Send the formattedDate labels to the line chart component:

```
  const chartData = {
    labels: [],
    datasets: [
      {
        label: label,
        data: [],
        backgroundColor: color,
        borderColor: color,
        borderWidth: 1,
        value: formattedDates
      },
    ],
  };
```

access it in the line component and change the tick values using a callback:

```
  return (
    <div>
      <Line 
        data={data}
        type="line"
        height={300} // set the height of the chart
        width={1300} // set the width of the char
        options= {{
          scales: {
              x: {
                  ticks: {
                      // add dates to x axis
                      callback: function(index) {
                          return data.datasets[0].value[index];
                      }
                  }
              }
          }
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```